# theatre layout image in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a theatre layout image (similar to the one found in many ticket booking apps) in which the seat color change when user clicks on it.  Also, the booked  and available seats should be shown in different colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one Button for each seat. This Button could show an image for example an icon for a seat. If the user clicks on it, another icon could be set for the clicked button in the `onClick()` method.  This other icon could be the icon for available seats but in another color.

The layout of the seats in a theatre could be achieved by the positioning of the buttons.

Comment: I think it will be hard for android devices. Make sense to use webview for this...

Comment: @edbaev Yes but I can't figure out a easier way than this. I also think, that on a smartphone with an display of let´s say 5 inch it's not that good to use, because the buttons would probable become very small. This means they are hard to click, what results in a poor user experience. But maybe he is planing on using his app on big tablet or something like this.

Comment: Jep :) on the small devices it will be ugly. I've researched this a month ago, and found only one solution - webView. But if you, @Shivani has some app with "native" design and solution - it make sense to decompile the app :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :) But now I am facing a different problem. Suppose user touched a seat and its color changed. Now next time when I start the app, it is not showing the changed image. What should I do to make this change permanent?

Comment: You could store the reserved seats in a sqllite database. And at every start of the app you'll check, whether the seats are reserved or not.

Comment: Please upvote and accept answers, if they helped you to solve your problem. So other users with the same problem can see, what helped to fix the issue.

Comment: But this would require one layout file for each screen. can we have any automate solution where we can upload an image and it detects the seat layout?