# Creating theatre layout for Android application

Tags: android, html, user-interface, android-layout, layout

I want to get theatre (cinema) layout information from a server and present it to the user in my android application. User should then be able to select seats.

These layouts would differ from theatre to theatre. I would get layout based on the theatre selected and present it to the user.

I am planning to use webview to display the information in the app([theatre layout image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669677/theatre-layout-image-in-android)).

How do I create these layouts for all the theatres (seats should be selectable)?

Note: Idea is to give control to the theatre owners to provide/update layout.

Note: Saw few softwares which can be used to create the layouts. But these would give the layouts as a single image. Rather than a HTML where seats are selectable.

Comment: I did it on a open-source application available on githib names OCiney, and without html. You can use our drawables if you want :) [https://github.com/florent37/OCiney](https://github.com/florent37/OCiney) [Activity](https://github.com/florent37/OCiney/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bdc/ociney/activity/TheaterDetailMovie.java) [Layout](https://github.com/florent37/OCiney/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_theater_detail_movie.xml) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/76sEP.png)

Comment: Thanks Florent. I tried launching the app and getting some exception. Couple of questions. Are you getting the layouts from the server? Can you share the screenshot of the seating?

Comment: the layout are created directly from the application. I don't have seatings in this applications sorry, just a placehoder image of seats in front of screen

Comment: I am bit confused on how the user selects the seat if its a placeholder image. Can you elaborate on this? If possible, can you provide a screenshot?